# React lifecycle hooks not working on redux state update

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using react with typescript and react-redux package.

did configure component as in documentations - https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start

console.log is working on connect function but component lifecycle not working.

> container.ts

````
import Toolbar from './Toolbar.Component';


export default connect<any, any, any>((store:any) => {
    console.log('++++++++++++++++++++',store.toolbarComponent);
    return store.toolbarComponent
}, {})(Toolbar)```
````

> component.ts

```
export default class ToolbarComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {  

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activeProperty: '',
            toolbarList: this.props.toolbarList
        };
        console.log('--- comp init ---', this.state);
        this.dispatchData = this.dispatchData.bind(this);
    }

    UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate(){
        console.log('-----', this.props.toolbarList, this.state.toolbarList)
    }

    componentWillUpdate(){   
        console.log('-----', this.props.toolbarList, this.state.toolbarList)
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(){
        console.log('-----', this.props.toolbarList, this.state.toolbarList)
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        console.log('-----', this.props.toolbarList, this.state.toolbarList)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `store.toolbarComponent` and do you have console errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with the spread operator

```
import Toolbar from './Toolbar.Component';

export default connect<any, any, any>((store:any) => {
    return { ...store.toolbarComponent }  <-- Here
}, {})(Toolbar)
```

**Explanation** - Component hooks is not detecting changes in `store.toolbarComponent` object and spread operator clone the `store.toolbarComponent` object and pass the cloned version.