# componentDidMount not firing on prop change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a nested component on my react App.

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {id : "1"};
  }
  render() {
    return <ShowChart id={this.state.id}/>;
  }
}
```

I render the component ShowChart from Home and pass this.state.id as a prop. The ShowChart is a component with redux connect().

```
class ShowChart extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {color: "red"};
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    //API_Call(this.props.id)
    //This API call uses props.id as parameter and redux store provides the API response
  }
  render() {
    return (<div>{API_response}</div>);
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        //
    };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        //    
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ShowChart)
```

I expect ShowChart to fire its componentDidMount whenever the value 'id' changes at Home Component. But it doesn't seem to behave so. I tried getDerivedStateFromProps(), componentDidUpdate()methods without any success.
Any solution or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: ``componentDidMount`` is called once and only once when the component mounts. For updates use ``componentDidUpdate``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I was not using the life cycle methods properly.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.id !== prevProps.id) {
       //API_Call(this.props.id)
    }
}
```

This solved the problem. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 3):

ComponentDidMount() will only fires once when the component is mounted to the dom,ComponentDidUpdate is called after componentDidMount() and can be useful to perform some action when the state/props changes.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  //api call
  //state update
}
```

i think what you want to do is re-render ShowCart when id changes, if so you can do

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {id : "1"};
  }
  render() {
    return <ShowChart id={this.state.id} key={this.state.id}/>;
  }
}
```

adding key to Component will force it to re-render when id value changes

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer: [React lifecycle hooks not working on redux state update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57969468/react-lifecycle-hooks-not-working-on-redux-state-update)

Also, why not make the API Call inside the constructor? As they are already available there.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount` runs only after a re-render. A component is re-renders only by state changes not prop changes.
If you want to change state on prop change use `componentDidUpdate` or `getDerivedStateFromProps`.