# How do I trigger re-rendering when a class gets new data from a prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, oop, react-state

Sorry for the awkward title, I'm not entirely sure how to word this question.

I have code that has two classes:
Class "BLE" gets Bluetooth data and has to be running in top level at all times.
Class "DeviceScreen" has components that need change whenever the bluetooth data updates.
I pass the data into "DeviceScreen" as a prop like this:

```
this.props.route.params.myBLE
```

While "DeviceScreen" is able to get the data whenever the state re-renders, I can't figure out how to trigger the re-render whenever the data in "BLE" updates. How do I trigger re-rendering when a class gets new data from a prop?

Comment: Did you try the `ComponentDidUpdate` method? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67356996/componentdidmount-not-firing-on-prop-change) may have your answer.

Comment: Please show more code

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.propA !== this.props.propA) {
    // ... do effect
  }
}
```